# How I can use Commonmark.js

Tags: javascript, markdown

Here is a quote from [official repository](https://github.com/commonmark/commonmark.js/#installing):

> For client-side use, you can do `make dist` to produce a standalone JavaScript file `js/dist/commonmark.js`, suitable for linking into a web page, or fetch the latest from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jgm/commonmark.js/master/dist/commonmark.js, or `bower install commonmark`.
>
> *Quote source: github.com/jgm/commonmark.js*

So, I downloaded commonmark.js file to my desktop and placed it together with my test file:

**test.html**

```
<script src="commonmark.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="commonmark.js"></script>

# header

text

text
```

... but is doesn't work.

I'm on Windows. I tested in both Chrome and Firefox. In Chrome Developer Tools there are no errors visible.

What I'm doing wrong?

The expected behaviour is to see the formatted text when I open this file in browser, [like shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kf95c.png)

I want it just for myselft desktop use. In other words, as replacement of Word. Open it with Sublime Text, write something, then open in Chrome and see the result. Something like Strapdown (strapdownjs.com). Maybe I'm on a wrong way?

Comment: read about [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/267029). You need a markdown-powered notepad for yourself, but you're asking how to use Commonmark.js (and it's not the right site to ask about it, btw). If you're already using Sublime Text, then there's already an existing solution for your problem. Please [edit] your question and fix it.

Comment: @gronostaj, thank for the comment! I know about the XY. What I want is something like [Strapdown](http://strapdownjs.com/). So, my attempt (as described in the question) is not a right way to accomplish it?

Comment: Strapdown is a tool for serving markdown documents from a static HTTP server. I don't think that's what you want. I think you want to type documents in markdown, preferably using ST, and then render them nicely formatted. Is that correct?

Comment: Honestly I don't see the difference. First step - I open Strapdown file (my-document.html) with Sublime or with another text editor/IDE, no matter, write there something formatted as markdown (# Header). And step 2 - I reopen this file in Chrome. As a result, I see the formatted HTML inside browser. As I supposed, I can get the same result just by adding commonmark.js to the top of the file. Maybe it was naive...

Comment: The difference is: one is asking for X and it's easily solvable; the other one is asking for Y which is not really what you need and harder to set up, especially that you don't know JS and SOP will prevent it from working in the most trivial way. Really, I know how to solve X in three minutes, I'm using it quite often. But you're asking for Y and my answer would be off-topic, even though X is what you really need.

Comment: Quick answer in comments: Sublime Text + Package Control + Markdown Preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **What I'm doing wrong?**

Lots.

1. That's not really a valid HTML file

   - You need some html tags and structure (see below)
   - You call the javascript library twice for reasons I cannot fathom.
2. Your page doesn't define a TextArea where people can type in text
3. You haven't instantiated the class as described under ["Usage"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commonmark)

   - You need to call the `parse` methed and pass it the entered text
   - you need to display the result of calling the `render` method

Basic example of HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Testing CommonMark.js</title>
    <script src="commonmark.js" />
    <script>
       // use commonmark ...
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

      forms, textareas etc

  </body>
</html>
```

See

- Source of  http://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/
- http://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/dingus.js

Comment: Thanks! **"Your page doesn't define a TextArea where people can type in text"** I want it just for myselft. In other words, as replacement of Word. Open it with Sublime Text, write something, then open in Chrome and see the result.

Comment: @jsv, OK,  *your page doesn't define a TextArea where **you** can type in text*.  ...  I suspect you really want [Markdown for Sublime Text](http://plaintext-productivity.net/2-04-how-to-set-up-sublime-text-for-markdown-editing.html) but didn't ask the question you really wanted answering. That's called an [X-Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Hmm... I'm not total newbie with HTML/CSS/JS, AsciiDoc and such things. I even work a little with AngularJS... Honestly, I don't understand why I need a text area. I'm going to write commonmark markup inside Sublime Text, not inside text area... In other words, I want something like [Strapdown](http://strapdownjs.com/).

Comment: @jsv, you need a source of text, that could be a file rather than a TextArea. My initial answer pointed you at the TextArea tag because your question asked about HTML and provided no information about an external source of the text. It is best to explain context in your question if it has a direct effect on the type of answers that you will accept. In this case it is a minor detail (skip to point 3. above), just use JS to read the file (you will likely have permissions issues here) and then feed that text to the `parse` method.

Comment: Okay, already upvoted the answer, I will try... :-) The upvote maybe not visible due to my low score. It will be visible later.